# Accepting Sql query in the form of argument in java code

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, plsqldeveloper, oracle-coherence

I am working on oracle coherence,have loaded data into the cache with the help of java code.I need help on how to accept random sql query in the form of argument in java to display output in the form of table.
This is the Sample sql query.

```
select dt,BCR,DCR,RCR,(BCR+DCR+RCR) as sum from (Select to_char(event_date,'DD-Mon-YY') as dt,
  case when sum(BCR_DNOM_D) in (0,NULL) then 0 else round((sum(BCR_NOM_D)*100/sum(BCR_DNOM_D)),2) end as BCR, 
  case when sum(TCASSALL) in (0,NULL) or (sum(TNDROP-cellgen_cell23spare))<0 then 0 else round((sum(TNDROP-cellgen_cell23spare)*100/sum(TCASSALL)),2) end as DCR,
  case when sum(RCR_DNOM_D) in (0,NULL) then 0 else (case when round((sum(RCR_NOM_D)*100/sum(RCR_DNOM_D)),2)>100 then 0
  else round((sum(RCR_NOM_D)*100/sum(RCR_DNOM_D)),2)end) end as RCR
  from EDW_BASE_table A where 1=1 
  group by event_date
  order by event_date)
```

Comment: Thanks Chanukya. I am new to java and sql coding,please suggest how to proceed with the issue.

Comment: iam not clear what you are asking ...@nidhi

Comment: I am working on : To integrate coherence with Ab Initio.
We have loaded Coherence cache 2G_Voice by fetching data from DB/flat file . We are able to search in cache using key : CELL_NAME+CLUSTER_ID+TOWN_NAME+CIRCLE_NAME and also able to search by select * query.
Now, Ab Initio will hit my coherence cache with sample query like below:
and coherence will have to accept this query in the form of argument with help of java.
Please suggest,how to do this in java and coherence so that the above SQL query will give desirable result.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Coherence is **NOT** a RDBMS. Coherence is a giant partitioned hashmap spread across multiple servers, hence it stores data in form of < Key, Value > where both key and value can be complex java objects and be queried against.

It will be very easy for you to write an Invocable class [Coherence Node based processing documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/coherence/develop-applications/api_processcache.htm#GUID-D5E1ED83-7F89-4944-97B5-75342AE3EF39) apply the business logic to get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Prabal.Your suggestion helped ,I was looking for a work around to do this.Is it possible to do this using filter?

Comment: Your query looks little complex don't think simple filters will be able to do the job on its own. You can have an invocable which might call filters and fetch data for you.